# T-SQL LAG function for returning previous rows with different WHERE condition

Tags: sql, group-by, window-functions, lag

I have data like:

table name: "Data"

```
ID  Name   Color  Value
1   A    Blue   1 
2   B    Red    2
3   A    Blue   3 
4   B    Red    4
5   B    Blue   3 
6   A    Red    4
```

Can I use a SQL LAG function to get for each Name that is Red, the previous value for for that name that was Blue (ordering by ID)?

Result set:

```
ID Name   Color   Value  PreviousValue

2  B    Red    2   NULL
4  B    Red    4   NULL
6  A    Red    4   3
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt and explain what issue you are facing.

Comment: in `SELECT` use `LAG` in `case`: `case when Color ='Red' then LAG(Value, 1) over(order by id ASC) else null end`

Comment: by the logic you presented id=4 should be value is null as well as there's no color = blue and name = b before it. can you have multiple blues and then multiple reds by the same name?

Comment: @DannySlor well spotted, I updated the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   *
from
(
select   *
        ,case when color = 'red' and color != lag(color) over(partition by name order by id) then lag(value) over(partition by name order by ID) end PreviousValue
from     t
) t
where    color = 'red'
order by id
```

| ID | Name | Color | Value | PreviousValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | B | Red | 2 | null |
| 4 | B | Red | 4 | null |
| 6 | A | Red | 4 | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SQBhYwpg)

Comment: Nice!  this was the highlight of my day :D